# Prevent Column from scrolling past fixed navbar in bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a column on my page that needs to become fixed when the column reaches the navbar which is fixed. I have tried affix however it is forcing the column to stay stuck in the original rendered position which is halfway down the page. This is a simple snippet of the layout.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> 
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Navbar markup -->
    </div>
</nav> 

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box box-solid box-success">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">Box Heading</h3>
            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body margin">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <!--  1 to many rows here -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">  
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><!-- This column should stick to the fixed navbar when scrolling reaches it  -->
                    <div class="affix">
                        <div class="well">
                            <div id="map" class="map"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried several solutions on SO and Google is only turning up fixing the navbar

Comment: Is the issue you are having is the column gets in the fixed position and doesnt become unfixed when you scroll back up? It would be helpful if you could provide a JS Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code. Also i am assuming you have read the documentation on Affix? (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)

Comment: @crazymatt Affix forces the div to get fixed in its original rendered position which is the bottom right of the page. This is wrong. The div should scroll freely with the page until it hits the navbar at the top of the page. At that time it should then be fixed and the top should never scroll past the NavBar.